# running background process at certain interval with different foreground process in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 3 functions in a java program:

- the first two are used for polling any SNMP device; all they do is get the inbound n outbound traffic.
- the third function gets any value based on the input user enters.

The main function is menu driven. It asks users to enter choices as to what value they need and accordingly the value is returned using the third function.
While this goes on I want the first two functions to run every 5 seconds and it shouldn't mess with the menu driven program.

Any ideas on how to do that ?

p.s.: I tried a few exapmles but they reset the menu (do while loop) every time they are done with the first two functions.

Comment: What do you mean "menu driven": as in you use a JMenu in Swing? What do you mean "they reset the menu"?

Answer (score 0):

Stab in the dark - would a Timer function calling a Task work?

Answer (score 0):

For first two function you could use

```
while(true) {
 thread1.start();
 thread2.start();
 Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

For third thread you should make Deamon thread(by thread3.setDeamon(true)) which runs background. In the run method of every kind of thread(which don't forget to implements Runnable or extends Thread) you could make what work is thread doing. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to go the `multithreading` way because SNMP communication induce possibly long timeouts waiting for a reply, and you do not want the timeouts to freeze the interface (waiting on the UI thread would be bad).

To make it simple, one *Thread* could be used to communicate for the "two functions", polling alternatively `function1()` and `function2()` (can be extended later with a `Thread Pool`).

The main thread can be used for your main input (like normal java programs).

Snippet for threaded logic, where `function1()` and `function2()` are time-consuming (note: there is no *sleep* since cadencing would be done within the polling in your functions, if you need to reduce polling frequency, use `wait(timeout)` and `notifyAll()` -- necessary to quickly exit when the user clicks Exit menu) :

```
while ( ! isTerminated() )
{
   function1();
   if ( isTerminated() )
       break;
   function2();
}
```